# Redirect to Login page after successful reset password

Tags: laravel-5.3

I wanted to redirect to the login page after the successful password reset in laravel 5.3? Currently it is redirecting to /home. I would be grateful if anyone has the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the redirection patch in the `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php` file

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: This answer worked for me when i write '/' in place of /home.

Answer (score 0):

After resetting the password, you would return some page. But instead you have to redirect the page to login, by `return redirect('login');`

Comment: After resetting the password it is redirecting directly to /home. Can you tell me where should i write return redirect('login'). I mean can you tell me the file name??

Comment: At the end of the class which you are using for resetting password